# Vim - how to remap "jump to next/previous paragraph"

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, neovim

In vim you can use `{` and `}` to jump between paragraphs.

Can someone help me change those keybingings? I'm trying to make them `Alt-Down` and `Alt-Up` respectively.

I've tried this so far:

```
map <ALT-DOWN> <S-{>
map <ALT-DOWN> <S-[>
map <ALT-DOWN> {
```

but no luck.

I'd like the shortcut to work in all vim modes, including edit mode.

Comment: from `:help key-notation`, the `Alt` key is represented by `<M-...>`. However I tried a few things, but my `Alt` key only seems to engage the items on the menu bar of my terminal, rather than being picked up by vim (which I run in the terminal)...

Comment: It seems this issue can be a little tricky: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9072/why-alt-key-mapping-not-working-in-vim-but-it-works-in-neovim, but it might be doable: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/how-to-map-alt-key

Comment: thanks for posting! actually managed to make it work (although not in insert mode). Do you want to add an actual answer and I'll mark it as correct? For anyone interested the final config lines are: map <M-DOWN> <S-}> and 
map <M-UP> <S-{>

Comment: Ah cool - for the insert mode have you tried with the `imap` as opposed to just `map`? (or `inoremap`?). I won't put an answer as I don't think I really understand the situation well enough... but you can answer it yourself and mark mark it as correct for future googlers.

Comment: good idea. Just tried it, but unfortunately doesn't work. It just prints "{" or "}" instead of moving the cursor. The reason is, I think, that that in insert mode shift-{ and shift-} aren't originally mapped to jumping paragraphs, and so remapping doesn't work. Tbh for now this solution is good enough for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from comments by @mattb above, the solution that (partially) worked is:

```sh
#all modes except insert
map <M-DOWN> <S-}>
map <M-UP> <S-{>

#insert mode
imap <M-UP> <esc><S-{>i
imap <M-DOWN> <esc><S-}>i
```

Note this on neovim, not vim.

PS credit for above is Matt's. Relevant links supplied:

- [Why alt key mapping not working in vim? but it works in neovim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9072/why-alt-key-mapping-not-working-in-vim-but-it-works-in-neovim)
- [How to map Alt key?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/how-to-map-alt-key)

Comment: oh maybe you could use the insert mode `ctrl+o` + `}`, which breaks out of insert mode, does the normal mode `}` jump, then drops back into insert mode? Maybe like this: `imap <M-UP> <ctrl-o><S-{>`?

Comment: close! your idea worked, but I had to modify it slightly, see above. Thanks a ton dude!